# Fading a content when hover a menu <li> issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm with a problem, and I need your help.

So, I'm trying to make a menu that show the content when you do a mouse hover in a li tag. And the first content need to be always showing when you do a mouse over on the first li option, or when no one li is hovered.

I tried to make this, and you can see a demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/sqftzuja/

As you can see, it's isn't work so fine and some times it show more than one content.

My script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#nav3 li:first-child").addClass("tab-active");
  $('#nav3 li').click(function() {


    var section4 = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $("#nav3 li").removeClass("tab-active");
    $(this).addClass("tab-active");

    $('.tv-corporativa').hide(); 
    $(section4).fadeIn(800);

   });
});
```

If anyone can help me improve it it will help me a lot!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try onmouseover instead of hover. here's the updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sqftzuja/1/

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/hover/ It takes in 2 function, hover in and out. On your fiddle, you only got 1

Comment: you're most welcome. let me post this as a solution if it works for you. you can accept it as an answer.

Comment: @user3130064 I've posted my solution as an answer. please accept it if it helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jquery `hover` takes two arguments, one is for the pointer entering the element and the other is for when it leaves the element.

e.g.

```
$('selector').hover(one_function, two_function)
```

you can either use hover and call the second function or use the `onmouseover` event.

here's the fiddle for onmouseover https://jsfiddle.net/sqftzuja/1/

Comment: If you do run your mouse really fast. You can reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You code is correct. You just need to `stop` the running animation.

`$(section4).stop( true, true ).fadeIn(800);`

This will solve you problem in the old code.

Answer (score 0):

you must stop fade in animation.when you fade in it effects after given interval.i updated fiddle as well

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#nav3 li:first-child").addClass("tab-active");
    $('#nav3 li').hover(function() {

    //console.info(  $(this).attr('href') );
    var section4 = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $("#nav3 li").removeClass("tab-active");
    $(this).addClass("tab-active");

    $('.tv-corporativa').stop().hide(); 
    $(section4).fadeIn(800);

  });
});
```